# Adding the end of a string, not containing a delimiter, to a vector

Tags: c++, string

I have a small program that takes a sentence like:

"I ,love to go running!" and ignores the punctuation and whitespace and counts the words and then displays each word line by line.

This example would output 5 for the number of words in the sentence.
The program would then output each word in the sentence individually.

```
I
love
to
go
running
```

The program works fine if the strings ends with a delimiter, a delimiter being any of one of these characters: ![,?._'@+]

If the strings ends without a delimiter.

For example,

I love to go running, pops

The program will only count five words not six and output

```
5
I
love
to
go
running
```

The word pops is completely ignored.

My question is what is going on when this happens, why is it happening?

Here is my code:

```
int main() {

string s = "";
string t = "";

vector<string> words;

getline(cin,s);

int size = s.length();

for(int i=0; i < size; ++i)
{
    if((s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z') || (s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z'))
     {  
        t += s[i];           
     }
    else
    {
        if(t != "")
        {
             words.push_back(t);
             t = "";
        }
    }
}
cout<<words.size()<<"\n";

for(vector<string>::iterator it=words.begin();it!=words.end();it++)
    {
     cout<<*it<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your for loops ends, you are not storing the `t`, which was created for the last word.

You should repeat the following code after the body of the for loop once more.

```
    if(t != "")
    {
         words.push_back(t);
         t = "";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that! That was a lot easier than the madness I was trying to code. Thank you for your help.